# C# MVC 5 The ticket cookie is cleared when the form authentication signs out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, formsauthentication, formsauthenticationticket

I need to access the cookies to get the user and password and then set them in the text boxes of the Login view because in that view is checked "Remember me".

LogOff method

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    //Session.Abandon();
    // sign out.
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
```

Initialization of sessions and cookies after a successful login.

```
private void InitializeSessionVariables(AgentDTO user)
{
    // SessionModel.AgentId = user.ID;
    Response.Cookies.Clear();
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,user.MobilePhone,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),true,"",FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    // Encrypt the ticket.
    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    // Create the cookie.
    HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket); // Name of auth cookie (it's the name specified in web.config) // Hashed ticket
    authenticationCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
    // Add the cookie to the list for outbound response
    Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);
}
```

Action Result of Login View
I have problem when I first log out and then try to access the cookie but it returns null because I run "FormsAuthentication.SignOut ();"

```
public ActionResult Index(LogonDTO model, string message = null, string reason = null)
{
    if (SessionModel.AgentMobilePhone != null) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    if (reason != null) message = "Su sessión ha expirado. Vuelva a loguearse.";
    ViewBag.Message = message;

    if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        model.Username = authTicket.Name;
        //model.Password = "in progress..."
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: As per this Article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/910443/understanding-the-forms-authentication-ticket-and-cookie , `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` will remove the cookie in any case. I'd assume in case of a persistent cookie, you do not call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` at all.

Comment: so, In my case should I never clean cookies?

Comment: I believe the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` should only be used, if the user has still a ticket/cookie but there is no open session on your server. This will remove the ticket from the user's browser and forces him "login" again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to store User information if he click on Remember Me checkbox

use

```
localStorage.setItem("UserName", "Smith");
```

to set values

and on Login page on document ready event of Jquery write below code

```
var UserName = localStorage.getItem("UserName");
if (UserName) $("#username").val(UserName);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: In the localstorage I can not save a password.

Comment: Use SessionID to store password on Server side. You can send request with SessionID to server which will pickup user information stored against that user and allow user to login.

Comment: Keeping it in a session is not recommended. It should necessarily be in a cookie because when entering the application today or tomorrow should put the user and password in the text boxes if it is checked Remember me. The session will die if I open the application the next day or if I close the application.